# Show that $\hat{G_1} \times \hat{G_2} \cong \widehat {G_1 \times G_2}$

Tags: topological-groups

Given a topological group $G$,  I need to prove that

$\hat{G_1} \times \hat{G_2} \cong \widehat {G_1 \times G_2}$

where $\hat{G} = \{ \chi | \  \chi : G \rightarrow S^1  \}$  $ \ \ , $  ($\chi $ is a continuous group homomorphism and $S^1$ is the multiplicative group of all complex numbers of absolute value one).  $\hat{G}$ itself is a topological group with the compact open topology.

Any help with this is appreciated!

Comment: Well, they aren't technically equal, they're isomorphic. What do you think the isomorphism is? (Also, are you treating the character group itself as a topological group, using the compact-open topology?)

Comment: Yes, $\hat{G}$ with the compact open topology is a topological group. I have made an edit.